# What is the number of self-inverse permutations on a set of cardinality $N$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations

Given a function (aka 'permutation') $f:A \rightarrow A$, where $A$ is a finite set such that $|A| = N$, we call it a self-inverse if $f(f(x)) = x$. The sequence of how many such functions exist for increasing cardinalities is given by [OEIS A000085](http://oeis.org/A000085). As far as I can tell, there is only a recursive formula for this sequence, is there a general formula?

Comment: I'm not actually sure if this was known or not, so feel free to comment if it was or if there things like that.

Comment: Posting a question you already knew the answer to is frowned upon here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. Like I said below: I put it here mainly as a reference for anyone (like me) who might be looking for the answer, since I couldn't find it anywhere. I think that's pretty much why SE lets you answer your own questions, but that might be (slightly) more common over at Math.SE .

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Comment: No, I don't think you should delete the question (actually you can't self-delete since one answer has been upvoted). One reason it's frowned upon is because it may make it appear the question is not meant as a 'real question'. This may be a peculiarity with 'MO culture' as you say, and there is nothing 'illegal' about it.

Comment: @ToddTrimble That makes sense, I'll refrain from doing this in the future, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Oh, by the way: "self-inverse" is fine, but I think it's more common to call such permutations *involutions*.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, Todd Leason pointed that out below, and I realized I could have easily looked up this result under the name 'involution'.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is closely related to the answers to the question [representations of $S_k \times S_j$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236982) (in the special case $j = N, k = 1$ which most answers actually concern themselves with), since the number you seek is also the sum of the degrees of the irreducible complex characters of $S_{N}$. As you write down, there is a precise summation formula for the number you want. However, there has been quite a bit of work on asymptotic estimates for it.

Comment: Thank you! Although that question goes above my head, I can see that my exact sum is found in the second answer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is equivalent to asking the number directed graphs $G$ such that every vertex of $G$ has an outdegree of $1$, and every vertex sits in exactly one cycle of length at most $2$.

Taking the case of $N = 4$ we can easily construct the number, which OEIS tells us is $10$ (I am copy and pasting from [my question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760723/how-many-graphs-with-vertices-a-b-c-d-exist-such-that-each-vertex-lies-in)):

> Case 1: All cycles are of length 1. This is equivalent to the identity
>   function, which we know is unique. However from a graph theoretic
>   point of view this is equal to $\binom{4}{4}$ because we are choosing
>   4 vertices to have cycle length one (notice that order does not matter
>   because cycles start and end in the same place, and if two functions
>   have the same cycles regardless of order they are equal).
>   $\binom{4}{4} = 1$, consistent with what we know about the identity.
>
> Case 2: One cycle is of length 2, and 2 are of length one. We know
>   that the two of length one are chosen by $\binom{4}{2}$ and the
>   reaming two vertices are forces to be in the cycles of length two (or
>   are 'chosen' by $\binom{2}{2}$).
>
> Case 3: 2 cycles of length 2, which is the same amount of choices as
>   above, since the two remaining ones are forced to be the cycle, however, because there are $2!$ ways to range two cycles we must divide by $2!$, giving $3$.
>
> Summing the amounts of functions from the three cases we get $10$.

In more generality we know that we will have similar cases. Specifically, the identity will always exist, and we will have to sum over the cases of having $i= 1,2,..,\lfloor \frac{N}{2} \rfloor$ $2$-cycles (since we can not have more than $\lfloor \frac{N}{2} \rfloor$ $2$-cycles on $N$ vertecies if every vertex sites in just one cycle), and we will have to divide by the number of ways there are to permute $i$ cycles.

For each case, we know this is the compound of choices, meaning we first have $\binom{N}{2}$ choices and then we much take $\binom{N-2}{2}, ...,\binom{N-2i}{2}$ choices corresponding to the $i$ cycles. So we will have the product $\prod\limits^{i}_{n=0} \binom{N-2n}{2}$. Summing all the cases (where we start with the case with one $2$-cycle, and adding 1 for the identity):

$$a(n) = 1+ \sum\limits^{\lfloor \frac{N}{2} \rfloor}_{i=1} \{\frac{1}{i!} \prod\limits^{i-1}_{n=0} \binom{N-2n}{2}\}$$

Comment: You posted this answer along with your question in the same minute.  So I wonder why you actually asked the question if you already had the answer ?

Comment: Two reasons: 1) I didn't know if this was known, since I couldn't find it anywhere, and I wanted to see if it was even correct, and 2) as a reference for anyone (like me) who might be looking for the answer. I think that's pretty much why SE lets you answer your own questions.

Comment: There are several similar "closed" formulas (in terms of sums) in OEIS.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev Although my idea of counting the number of graphs isn't novel (it's listed as Don Knuth's contribution on OIES), and there are a few other ones in terms of sums of other sequences, I couldn't find one with an explicit form like this.

Comment: See for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795541/involutions-of-s-n or google for "number of involutions in symmetric group". BTW: According to the acctepted SE answer the product in your formular can be resolved.

Comment: @ToddLeason I stand corrected, it is both trivial and well known. Thank you  for linking to those places.

Comment: The formula a(n)=Sum_{k=0..[ n/2 ]} n!/((n-2*k)!*2^k*k!) is the fourth line of the OEIS "Formula" section.

Comment: @IraGessel Oh, you're 100% right, I didn't even know OEIS had a formula section until you pointed it out. That's also probably what Alex Degtyarev was referring to too.